# R and dplyr: case_when throws 'incorrect length error' despite not being asked to evaluate group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a panel dataset where some groups have observations starting at an earlier year than others and would like to calculate the change in value from the earliest possible time period. I expected that by using *case_when* within *mutate*, R would not try to evaluate the code for groups where the earlier dates do not exist, but this does not seem to be the case. I have included a reprex below.

```
library("dplyr")

dataset <- data.frame(names=c("a","a","a","b","b"),
                      values=c(2,3,4,2,3),
                      dates=c("2010","2011","2012","2011","2012"))

dataset_calc <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(new_val = case_when(names=="a" ~ values-values[dates=="2010"],
                             TRUE ~ values-values[dates=="2011"]))
```

Is there a better solution for what I would like to do?
The resulting dataframe should be something like:

```
  names values dates new_val
1     a      2  2010       0
2     a      3  2011       1
3     a      4  2012       2
4     b      2  2011       0
5     b      3  2012       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you arrage the data by group, then you can just subtract off the first value for each group

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  arrange(dates) %>% 
  mutate(new_val = values - first(values))
```

If you wanted to hard code different reference years, you would want to use the `case_when` part over the year rather than the values. For example

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  mutate(
    ref_year = case_when(names=="a" ~ "2010", TRUE~"2011"),
    new_val = values - values[dates==ref_year],
    ref_year = NULL
)
```

(you don't need to use the temporary `ref_year` variable, I just added it here for clarity of how the function was working)

Comment: Thank you, and indeed this would be possible in this particular example - as would, I guess, something like using values[dates==min(dates)]. But in cases where it is not necessarily the first value (e.g. if A went back to 2009 and I wanted the difference with 2010), how could I specify the date?

Comment: Is that going to be different for every group? How will you specify the reference for each group? Do you want to hard code it?

Comment: Yes, it would likely be hardcoded in this instance as I would know what specific dates to use (as in the example). More generally, I was curious whether there is an alternative to case_when for these kind of instances where I would like the code to ignore groups who do not have the relevant row.

Comment: If the data for the reference is not coming from the data itself, then you'd have to use `if` statements to get conditional evaluation. `case_when` is a vectorized function and it will evaluate all parameters. It does not do conditional evaluation. Instead you could use the case_when around the date value. I've updated my answers to show that version as well